# SQL server: insert into using select and other parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server

I got 3 tables: **projects**, **managers** and **project_manager**

**managers**

- manager_id (int, PK)
- manager_name

**projects**

- project_id (int, PK)
- project_name

**project_manager**

- project_id  (int, PK)
- manager_id  (int, PK)

Assume that a manager is currently logged-in (so we know what **manager_id** is) and he want to create a new **Project**, by entering a name into txtName textbox and hit "create" button. I tried to write:

(1) a query to insert a new project (name) into **projects** table and

(2) a single query that insert **project_id** & **manager_id** into **project_manager** table

but got syntax error at the third query string and this is not a good way since inserting into projects table (query 1) may be succeeded but inserting into other table (query 2) may be failed, I dont know much "advanced stuff" of SQL, definitely need help:

```
string CS = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CTECS"].ConnectionString;
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS))
{
    string q1 = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [projects] WHERE project_name = @Name";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(q1, con);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", txtName.Text);
    con.Open();
    int i = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
    if (i < 1)
    {
        string Command = "INSERT INTO [dbo].[projects] (project_name) VALUES (@Name)";
        cmd = new SqlCommand(Command, con);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", txtName.Text);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        Command = "INSERT INTO [project_manager] (project_id, manager_id) VALUES (SELECT project_id FROM [projects] WHERE project_name = @Name, @ID)";
        cmd = new SqlCommand(Command, con);
        // Provide the value for the parameter
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", txtName.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", currentUser.userID.ToString());
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    else
    {
        Panel1.Visible = true;
        lblMessage.CssClass = "alert alert-error";
        lblMessage.Text = "This project's name has been already used.";
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: no that was right, my bad..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the third sql statement should be:

INSERT INTO [project_manager] (project_id, manager_id) SELECT project_id, @ID FROM [projects] WHERE project_name = @Name

Comment: He will end up inserting multiple records into the table, if he has got multiple projects with the same name.

Comment: Agreed. The best approach would be to use SCOPE_IDENTITY() after insert into [projects] to get the project_id (assuming project_id is an identity column)

Comment: @MikeHixson Can you please show a complete answer that explain your idea, I have hard time to figure out it?

Comment: @RonaldinhoState your original post before you edited it said: "I tried this but got syntax error at the third query string". My reply was to that statement. If you replace your third sql statement with the one in my answer it should take care of your syntax error.

Comment: @MikeHixson I mean the "better" idea that use SCOPE_IDENTITY() you mentioned in your comment

Comment: Ah right. So after you insert into projects table you can get the project_id that was created by executing: SELECT @project_id = SCOPE_IDENTITY(). Then you could insert that into project_manager, without having to select the project_id by name from project table. The answer provided by Hamlet Hakobyan shows how to do this with a stored procedure.

Answer (score 2):

Do you use the server in single_user mode? I don't think so. At first you must do it in the transaction. The best way to do it - SP. Checking the existence of project doesn't guarantee that it not exists when you insert it.

```
CREATE PROC usp_InsertProject(@project_name varchar(255), @manager_id int)
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON
DECLARE @project_id int
BEGIN TRY
  BEGIN TRAN
    INSERT INTO [dbo].[projects] (project_name) VALUES (@project_name)
    SELECT @project_id = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
    INSERT INTO [project_manager] (project_id, manager_id)
                                  VALUES(@project_id, @manager_id)
  COMMIT TRAN
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    SELECT ERROR_NUMBER() AS ErrorNumber
       ,ERROR_MESSAGE() AS ErrorMessage
   ROLLBACK TRAN
END CATCH

GO
```

then

```
string CS = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CTECS"].ConnectionString;
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS))
{
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("usp_InsertProject", con);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@project_name", txtName.Text); // you must validate text value before passing
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@manager_id", currentUser.userID);

    con.Open();
    using(SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
        if(reader.Read())
        {
           // the error occured in SP
           // reader[0] is error number
           // record[1] is error message
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I had a hard time to understand this answer but I will do research about "transaction" SQL.

Comment: Notice, that you must have unique constraint on `projects.project_name`, if you want to avoid projects with duplicate name.

Answer (score 1):

Your logic is not correct here in the first place

```
SELECT project_id FROM [projects] WHERE project_name = @Name
```

may return multiple results. You may have checks in place that ensure that there can be exactly one project with one name, but system doesn't knows that and you will end up inserting multiple records into the table

A work around can be that you change it to (just to make it work)

```
INSERT INTO [project_manager] (project_id, manager_id) SELECT project_id, @ID FROM [projects] WHERE project_name = @Name
```

But, not recommended.

You need to save the id that you are generating for the project name and pass them to your query here.

```
INSERT INTO [project_manager] (project_id, manager_id) VALUES (@ProjectID, @ID)
```

Comment: Can you please explain the term "...but system doesn't knows that and you will end up inserting multiple records into the table"?

Comment: Let's assume that there are 2 records with project name "Project ABC" in the database. Then your statement will insert 2 entries in the project_manager table.

Comment: Cannot be happened because the 1st query "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [projects] WHERE project_name = @Name" will check if the name is exciting or not, am I right?

Comment: You can place multiple checks in place for avoiding this. But, you need to do it the proper way.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you transfer your whole logic in stored procedure which is safe and easily maintainable. Also there is only one hit to sqlserver rather than 3 in your case.

Also good as use @@identity or SCOPE_IDENTITY() to get id of inserted project-id.

So make one sp and code like @Hamlet-Hakobyan suggested. Try to make world simple from complex, not complex from simple.

Your code is good to understand as basic things, but not in professional scenario.